# In AppEngine for Java, how do you get the name of the instance: e.g. instance.appspot.com

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to get what the name of my instance is from within the app.

THANKS

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can use `SystemProperty.applicationId.get()`, see here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Environment

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty.html